# Jquery code for hierarchal element is not working for a particular value in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a sidebar drop-down menu, which is being operated using jquery, but when user clicks on the item the page refreshes and the menu collapses. To solve this,that is to keep it expanded, I decided to compare the REQUEST_URI with menu item URL, if found I will trigger the click event. To accomplish this I used the snipped

```
$("a[href='<?php echo $citems->url;?>']").parents("li").parents("ul.dropdown-menu").prev(".dropdown-toggle").trigger("click");
```

Which works for all item except for a particular item which appears at third last position in menu item list. Below is the code I am executing in which I am facing the issue:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>      
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav asurion-sidebar" >
          <?php 
            $nav_menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'left-sidebar' );
            $menu_items = wpse170033_nav_menu_object_tree( $nav_menu_items );   
            $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ); 



            foreach($menu_items as $items)
            {

                $parents1 = get_post_ancestors( $items->ID );  

                if(count($items->children) > 0)
                {

                ?>
                 <li class="dropdown first-level">
                   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa <?php echo $items->classes[0];?>" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $items->post_title;?> <i class="fa fa-angle-down menu-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
                     <?php
                      foreach($items->children as $citems)
                      {
                         if(count($citems->children) > 0)
                         {?>
                            <li class="dropdown thirdlevel ">
                             <a  style="cursor:pointer" class="dropdown-toggle naveen" data-toggle="dropdown-submenu"><i class="fa <?php echo $citems->classes[0];?>" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $citems->post_title;?><i class="fa fa-angle-down menu-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-submenu forAnimate lastlevel" role="menu">    
                               <?php
                                 foreach($citems->children as $ccitems)
                                 {
                                     if(strpos($ccitems->url,'localhost')){
                                        $sea_domain = 'localhost';
                                     }elseif(strpos($ccitems->url,'asurion.com')){
                                        $sea_domain = 'asurion.com';
                                     }
                                     $compareUrl = explode($sea_domain,$ccitems->url)   ;                       
                                            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $compareUrl[1]){
                                     ?>
                                     <script>
                                     $(document).ready(function(){
                                     $("a[href='<?php echo $ccitems->url;?>']").parents("li").parents("ul.dropdown-submenu").prev("a[data-toggle='dropdown-submenu']").trigger("click");
                                    });
                                    </script>
                                     <?php }
                                    echo "<li><a target='".$ccitems->target."' href='".$ccitems->url."'>".$ccitems->post_title."</a></li>";
                                 }
                               ?>
                              </ul> 
                            </li>
                         <?php
                         }  
                        else
                        {
                        if(strpos($citems->url,'localhost')){
                                $sea_domain = 'localhost';
                             }elseif(strpos($citems->url,'asurion.com')){
                                $sea_domain = 'asurion.com';
                             }
                             $compareUrl = explode($sea_domain,$citems->url);        
                            echo "<li><a target='".$citems->target."' href='".$citems->url."'>".$citems->post_title."</a></li>";
                            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $compareUrl[1]){
                                ?>
                                <script>
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                $("a[href='<?php echo $citems->url;?>']").parents("li").parents("ul.dropdown-menu").prev(".dropdown-toggle").trigger("click");
                             });
                         </script><?php
                         }
                        }
                      }
                     ?>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                <?php
                }
                else
                {
                if(get_the_title($post->ID)=="Dashboard" && $items->post_title=="Home" && count($parents)==0)
                 {
                     echo  "<li class='active'><a target='".$items->target."' href='".$items->url."'> <i class='fa ".$items->classes[0]."' aria-hidden='true'></i>".$items->post_title."</a></li>";
                 }
                 else
                 { 
                     echo  "<li><a target='".$items->target."' href='".$items->url."'> <i class='fa ".$items->classes[0]."' aria-hidden='true'></i>".$items->post_title."</a></li>";
                 }

                }
            }

          ?>
        </ul> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Here is array being iterated for sidebar menu:[Array](https://jsfiddle.net/t8vwhjqa/), Here in the array one of the item for which the jquery snippet is failing is under "Device" > "Phone Simulators"

This is the [Extracted HTML code](https://jsfiddle.net/y5Lc16rz/) from Source Code (It doesnt contain js code as fiddle doesnt allow js code to be writtent in html section, to find JS code, scroll above)

Comment: Question updated with Array being iterated in a jsfiddle url with a sample item where the snippet is failing in between the loop

Comment: Can you post your final `HTML` code please? Not php. I'm not good at php(maybe someone can), so I can't know your `html` structure at all.

and your jsfiddle,alse show nothing except a heap of words. I want to help you but I cant

Comment: @LIXer Here is the final HTML extracted from Source, since JS fidle do not accept the JS code in html section, I have removed the js code from it. If you find the JS code, it has been mentioned in Question: https://jsfiddle.net/y5Lc16rz/, find <nav> tag in which the issue is being encountered

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that why you output

```
<script>
                                 $(document).ready(function(){
                                 $("a[href='<?php echo $ccitems->url;?>']").parents("li").parents("ul.dropdown-submenu").prev("a[data-toggle='dropdown-submenu']").trigger("click");
                                });
                                </script>
```

in a **loop**, it will make your HTML code looks messy. and you should not output so many `$(document).ready(...)` at all.

you can give your `<A />` a special className like 'xxx', and output the script code before `</body>`.

```
<script>
                                 $(document).ready(function(){
                                 $("a.xxx").parents("li").parents("ul.dropdown-submenu").prev("a[data-toggle='dropdown-submenu']").trigger("click");
                                });
                                </script>
```

it's a little better.

and if you want to keep the menu's status, you should use `cookie` or `localStorage`, not by this way.

and jsfiddle want you separate your html, css, js code, but through your way, your html and js can't be separated, it's not good. you can provide some css make the jsfiddle result page looks better, it can helps someone to understand your structure.

Comment: Does Localstorage, stays intact with page refresh?

Comment: @OMTheEternity of cause. you can read some basic tutorial about it, like on MDN. localStorage may store data forever only when user clean it handy, but, it just `local`.